exclude certain categories from the list at the end of the blog post
I'm trying to achieve the same as the OP here using the same structure (), viz I simply want to exclude certain categories from being displayed in the 'filed under' list at the end of  a blog post.
BUT when I add the suggested solution to my theme file/functions.php it creates a serious error that breaks the site.
Does anyone have any idea why this would be?
Is there any other way to achieve the simple aim of excluding certain categories/tags from the list at the end of the blog post?
